# How to filter a Cubeset with a filter expression to calculate ytd Values

Tags: excel-pivot

I want to filter a simple cubeset to calculate Year-To-Date Values in a Excel Pivot Datamodell

There are ways I tried:

1. with a From - To expression - this works but depends on the existens of the start and end month in the Datamodell
2. with a filter expression - this works NOT for me, the filter is not appliend and the Cubevalue function returns no value.
   [image]

The sample file with all data is avaiable here:
https://my.hidrive.com/lnk/Y3ASXPQg

I'm looking for a way:

1. to use from - to and handle the problem of missing start or end month
2. to make the filter expression working

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the missing Keyword was "Member_Value".

If you change the above shown Formulas to

=CUBEMENGE("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"filter([Bereich].[Month].[All].Children,[Bereich].[Month].Member_Value <  6)";"Set filtered")

it works fine.